# How to allow to post in Google groups without moderation after first approved post?

Tags: google-groups

I thought that with this setting

[image]

only the first post by a user is moderated and once it is accepted, they no longer need moderation. However, I've got a second mod notification and had to approve the second post by the same user. This should be somewhat frustrating for users, so I wonder what am I doing wrong? How to allow their post automatically once the first one got approved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When approving incoming posts from new members, there's a box to always allow future messages from that member.

[image]